# How to save a list in a csv file using sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint, export-to-csv

I have `SharePoint` list with me. I want to save that list in `.csv` without any use of third party tool or powershell (because it will not deal with database in my case), how can I do that using `SharePoint` online `-office 365`?

Comment: plz show us what have you tried so far ...

Answer (score 0):

Go to your library -> Library Tab -> Export To Excel

Answer (score -1):

This is Code is to export file in .csv format.

```
<?php
    //Database connection starts
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    include_once('includes/config.php');
    //Database connection ends

    //export .csv file starts here
    $filename = "testing-exports.csv";

    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    $insquery = "SELECT username FROM r_institution where status=1";
    $insresults = $conn->query($insquery);
    foreach ($insresults as $rs) {
        $row = array();
        $row[] = stripslashes($rs["username"]);
        $content[] = $row;
    }
    $content = array();
    $title = array("Institution Emails");
    foreach ($insresults as $rs) {
        $row = array();
        $row[] = stripslashes($rs["username"]);
        $content[] = $row;
    }
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fputcsv($output, $title);
    foreach ($content as $con) {
        fputcsv($output, $con);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Abdul, but as i know Sharepoint Online do not allow to write php or c# code. only client side script allowed. Correct me if i wrong! I am very new to sharepoint online.(SharePoint Online is licensed on a per-user basis. You can purchase SharePoint Online as a standalone plan or included as part of Office 365 plans. Learn more. Licensing details are available here)